# redsys Ds_Merchant_MerchantURL web api c#

Tags: c#, http, post, http-post

im trying to create a Http Post method to recive the result of payment transactions.
The problem is that I don't know how to create post method in a web api (MVC) that recived the data. (.NET)
The documentation says that I need to create a CGI, Servlet, etc that be able to interpret virtual TPV response but I don't Know how to create it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean literally the first thing any tutorial teaches you, how to create a controller and an action? Such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller

My point of view is that you usually can't do much with any technology without a brief look at the documentation.

Comment: Sorry for my explanation, I speak english very bad.
I know how to create a controller and a action but the problem is that in virtual tpv documentation explains that i need to create a post method that be able to catch all parameters. I don't know how to do that because when I define a post method I need to define all parameters.

Comment: Sorry, in that case I have no idea what TPV is. If you need the action to match with any kind of request you can simply define the parameter as a string and then do what you want with what you receive, like deserialize it if it's a JSON string. If I misunderstood or this will not work for some reason then you need to provide more information.